# what does $\text{Alt} (\omega^1 \otimes \omega^2) $ imply?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tensor-products

I am trying to prove that covector fields $\omega^1$ and $\omega^2$ on a finite-dimensional vector space are linearly dependent if and only if their wedge product is zero.

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose that $\omega^1$ and $\omega^2$ are linearly dependent,

Then $c_1 \omega^1 +c_2 \omega^2=0$ for some nonzero constant $c_1,c_2$. Therefore, $\omega^1= a \omega^2$, where $a=-\frac{c_2}{c_1}$. Therefore, $\omega^1 \wedge \omega^2=a \omega^2 \wedge \omega^2=0$.

$\Leftarrow$ Now, suppose that they are linearly independent, so we can extend a dual basis $\{\omega^1,\omega^2\}$ to $\{\omega^1,\omega^2,…,\omega^n\}$, so

$\omega^1 \wedge \omega^2\wedge …\wedge \omega^n\neq 0$

Hence $\omega^1\wedge \omega^2\neq 0$. This means that $\omega^1\wedge \omega^2= 0$ implies $\omega^1,\omega^2$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: You don't have a complete sentence. Do you mean "What does $\text{Alt}(...) = 0$" imply? I think you want to think about properties of wedge product, rather than going back to the definition. I also think you have a misconception here. Covector fields are $1$-forms, so $k=l=1$. If you "forgot" to use that in your forward proof, your proof is incorrect.

Comment: @TedShifrin I edited my post and added my solution for the first part.

Comment: Note that to say $\omega^2\wedge\omega^2=0$, what are you using? Here's a hint for the other direction: If $\omega^1\ne 0$, extend to a basis for the dual space. Now proceed.